# Killing parallelizable manifolds

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Recently I came across the notion of *Killing parallelizable manifolds*, which, as the name suggests, are those manifolds $M^n$ that admit $n$ linearly independent global Killing vector fields. For now, the only example I know is the Euclidean space. Could you give me others?

Comment: Any Lie group with a left-invariant metric will do